# Cross browser issue. Input Type inside a <td> works different in Chrome

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

When i use IE it works perfectly fine. But same code doesnt work in Chrome.
here is the code :

```
<td class="AttachOnMouseOutText" id="fileid" nowrap="nowrap" style="padding-right:10px;" valign="top" onClick="fad_open();" onMouseOver="highlightBG('fileid',0,'add','add_over.gif');this.style.cursor='hand'; return true;" onMouseOut="highlightBG('fileid',1,'add','add.gif'); return true;">

<p class="Margin" style="position:relative;">                               
    <input type="file" name="AttachLink" style="position: absolute; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(style=0, opacity=0); width:5px; height:50px; cursor: hand; left:-26px;" title="Add File Attachment" onChange="getWeblink();" size="40" float="right">                                                                   
        <img src="#ContactsImagePath#add.gif" alt="Add File Attachment" border="0" align="middle" name="add" id="add" onClick="fad_open();">
</p>


    <span>&nbsp;Add File</span>
```

Here the "input type=file" works great in IE (clicking on the image correctly), but when tried in Chrome, the input type is somewhere on the top left-side of the screen.
[image: IE Chrome]

Comment: Plz provide a fiddle of it. So that we can test on different browsers

Comment: Refer this post - http://dipaksblogonline.blogspot.in/2012/07/styling-input-type-file.html

Comment: I guess it has something to do with "filter". Like in the code it is :  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(style=0, opacity=0); width:0px; height:50px; cursor: hand; left:-26px;.... because the opacity is 0 it is somewhat hidden behind the <td>... but the filter may work only for microsoft IE. Can you suggest any filter for Chrome..?